# git commit not working with Git Bash

Tags: git

I am newbie in GIT. When I try to commit some files and it gives me the following warnings:

> modified content, untracked content

My folder structure like:

```
.git

   ---- files

   ----- another-folder

   ---- .git

   ---- files

----- another-folder

---- .git

 ---- files
```

I was downloading git repository for learning purpose and move all downloading files into my repository. Looking forward to the answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a warning, that's just how git works. It's simply letting you know what files have been modified but aren't selected for inclusion in this commit.

Answer (score 0):

The files should be added to the index (locally) first. You can do this by executing the add command like this:

```
git add --all
```

or

```
git add somefile.txt
```

After the files have been added, you can commit them.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps. Hope it'll work

- Remove the .git directories from those another folder (this can
  create submodule)
- then run **git rm -rf --cached another-folder**
- then re-added the directories with a **git add -A** from above
- then **git commit -m "your commit message"**
- then **git push origin your-branch-name**

It's making sure those directories aren't their own repository, after cleaning out git knew about them beforehand and then re-added them fresh.

Comment: I wouldn't execute commands without knowing what they do. Happy it worked for md sajib but the answer is far from reusable as it is. Just sayin'

Comment: It's making sure those directories aren't their own repository, after cleaning out git knew about them beforehand and then re-added them fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Git is showing that because it is detecting some files which are modified but not yet tracked by you. To do that, run:

`git add filename`

This will track the file and stage them on the index. You can commit after that.

However, there might be some folders or files that you want to ignore. In that case, make a `.gitignore` file and add them in each line.

**.gitignore**

```
# a comment
aDir/
somefile.txt
```

You can also specify glob patterns to match a group of files.

```
# * matches 0 or more characters 
*.txt
```

For more details,  check out [.gitignore docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).